# For cycle to build a table inserting figure

Tags: tables, macros, graphics, minipage, pgffor

I'm trying to build a two column table in which minipage environment is used. In \xdef block i can't use "minipage" but i can, instead, in \gdef.
My purpose will be to build double table like this in entire page.
How can i resolve the problem ?

```
\def\TEMP{}%
\foreach \n in {0,...,2}
  {
  \xdef\TEMP {\unexpanded\expandafter{\TEMP}\noexpand 
              \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
                  \includegraphics[width=\line{figure\n.png}%
              \end{minipage}
              }%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\TEMP 
      &  
      \begin{minipage}[!htb]{.2\textwidth}
        Name:\\name figure\\\\
        id:\\ id figure
      \end{minipage}
      \\ \hline
      }%
  }%
              
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
    \hline
    Figure & Info \\ \hline \hline
    
    \TEMP

     \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you can't put includegraphics in an xdf (unless you protect it with \noexpand` ir `\unexpanded` but why put it in a minipage it is aready a box, what is the minipage doing? also minipage  does not take an argument of the form `[!htb]` what is the intent of that (or simply delete it if it isn't intended)

Comment: `\begin{table}[!htb]` did you intend to prevent this table being place on a page of tables? I would include `p` and not include `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach with an interface to `\int_step_function:nnnN` that can even be used to build tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\forintegers}{mO{1}mm}
  { % #1 = start, #2 = step (optional, default 1)
    % #3 = end, #4 = template
    \fabri_forintegers:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabri_forintegers:nnnn
  {
    \cs_gset:Nn \__fabri_forintegers_function:n { #4 }
    \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } \__fabri_forintegers_function:n
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__fabri_forintegers_function:n {} % initialize

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabular}{ @{} c c @{} }
\toprule
Figure & Info \\
\midrule \addlinespace

\forintegers{0}{2}{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure#1.png}
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    Name: \\ name figure \\[2ex] id: \\ id figure
  \end{minipage}
  \\ \addlinespace
}

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\forintegers` is the starting point; an optional argument for the step follows (default 1), then the end point. The last argument is a template, where `#1` stands for the current integer in the loop.

[image]

Note. The `draft` option is used in order to produce fake images.

---

You can also do it with `\foreach`, but it's clumsier. Just define a local macro to which you can pass (the expansion of) `\n`. Here the table is typeset with rules, just for comparison.

Never do `\\\\` to “leave vertical space”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]

\gdef\TEMP{}% initialize
\newcommand{\tablecell}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure#1.png}%
  \end{minipage}%
  &  
  \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
    Name:\\name figure\\[2ex]
    id:\\ id figure
  \end{minipage}
  \\ \hline
}
\foreach \n in {0,...,2}{%
  \xdef\TEMP{\unexpanded\expandafter{\TEMP}\noexpand\tablecell{\n}}%
}
              
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
\hline
Figure & Info \\ \hline \hline
\TEMP
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These solutions are wonderful ! The first one, maybe, is too difficult for me be, so i will opt for the second one that you have suggested. I'm still a newbie about latex codes. I still cant't leave a feedback on community but i invite other users to leave a like to yuor answer. Really thanks :))